# How to set date format for JsonObjectMapper in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-integration, objectmapper, jsr310

I am converting my Java object to `Map` using Spring Integration `ObjectToMapTransformer`'s `transformPayload()`.

Everything works fine except that the `Instant` fields in my object are getting broken into `epochSecond` and `nano`, which in turn throws exception while persisting in data-store (MongoDB).

This is the Spring Integration `JsonObjectMapper` being used to convert the `Object` to `Map`:
`private final JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = JsonObjectMapperProvider.newInstance();`

My question is how can I configure date format for the above mapper. Just like `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper::configure()`, do we have any similar options here?
 I cannot find any, neither in source code nor on internet!!

I also tried enabling/disabling `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` in my `application.properties`, but no joy!

I have `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency in my `pom.xml`

How to get the `Instant` in correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should add support for custom `JsonObjectMapper` injection. That way you would be able to build `Jackson2JsonObjectMapper` based on desired `ObjectMapper`.

Please, raise a JIRA ticket on the matter and don't hesitate with the contribution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Meanwhile as a workaround I'd suggest a pair of `ObjectToJsonTransformer`/`JsonToObjectTransformer`:

```
.transform(Transformers.toJson(jsonObjectMapper(), ObjectToJsonTransformer.ResultType.NODE))
.transform(Transformers.fromJson(Map.class, jsonObjectMapper()))
```

Comment: Did you mean: `.transform(Transformers.toJson(jsonObjectMapper(), ObjectToJsonTransformer.ResultType.NODE).transform(message))` instead?

Comment: Based on your answer I am able to prevent my `Instant` field from getting broken into `epochSecond` and `nano` by defining my own custom jackson mapper as: `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();` and then using the same in the workaround you suggested: `Map objectMap = (Map<String, Object>) transformer.transform(Transformers.toJson(new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(mapper), ObjectToJsonTransformer.ResultType.NODE).transform(message)).getPayload();`
Will raise a JIRA ticket for custom mapper support. Looking forward to contribute.

Comment: Well, I even think that can include that `findAndRegisterModules()` as our-of-the-box option by default